# Selecting :after element not working in Jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, less

I am creating a tool tip component for all input box and for text area my code is coming like

```
<div class="tooltip is-text-area show">
        <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion" class="my-textarea" style="text-transform: uppercase;"></textarea>
        <span class="tooltip-text" style="height: 14px;">Contect of tooltip</span>:after
    </div>
```

the input type can be text , checkbox or select box. In the css I have harcoded the value of bottom. but when  I use text are this tooptip is covering entire my input area , so I am tring to change the bottom property of tooltip-text and :after element using jquery to the height of element I am using .

My CSS is below

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip .tooltip-text {
  position: absolute;
  **bottom: 26px;**
  left: 0;
  background: #F47826;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 160px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
.tooltip.show .tooltip-text {
  display: block;
}
.tooltip.show:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  **bottom: 21px;**
  left: 11px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #F47826;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

I used below code to change the bottom property of tooltip-text and :after element

```
$("#descripcion").parent().hover(function(){$(this).attr('bottom','100px')}) ;
$("#descripcion").parent().find('span').attr('bottom','100px')}) ;
```

But it is not woking. Any help will be appreciated. how to select the after element

Answer (score 1):

An attribute is something like `id`, `style`, `class` etc, see below

```
<div class="something"></div>
```

however, a style is not an attribute, and does not use the `attr()` method, but the `css()` method

```
$("#descripcion").parent().hover(function(){
    $(this).css('bottom','100px');
});
```

You can of course not access pseudo elements like `:after` with jQuery